# Reversing internal function, can't call it with injected DLL

Tags: x86, c++, dll-injection

I'm currently learning RE. I've chosen to do so by trying to RE Skyrim for PC. I'm trying to call the ingame function for printing to the console, I'm doing this via an Injected DLL.

The function call looks like this

```
mov eax,tesv.1095FB8
mov edx,dword ptr ds:[1B10B58]
push eax
push tesv.1095FAC
push edx
call <tesv.ConsoleLog>
add esp,C
```

When called the arguments look like this

[image]

I believe the typedef for this function would be

```
typedef void(__cdecl *f_ConsoleLog)(uintptr_t ptr1, const char* ptr2, ...);
```

However calling the function causes an access violation, I've even tried to call it using inline ASM exactly as the aforementioned assembly does.

I'm quite stuck and don't know where to look next, could anyone point me in the correct direction?